# Closed cases showing in omni supervisor tab

Tags: case, queue, omnichannel, skill-based-routing, omni-supervisor

Closed cases are showing under an Omni Supervisor queue backlog.

[image]

Is this the default behavior? or can we do any customization?
Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using skill based omni, you have the option to filter the status from the service channel settings.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is working

Comment: Hii. This is working for new cases.
But the old cases keep staying in the backlog